# Second Order Linear Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $y''+y'-2y=0$, $t_0 = 0$

I need to use Abel's theorem

So I get $W(y1,y2) = ce^{(-t)}$

What should I do next?

Comment: What is your goal, exactly? Solve the equation?

Comment: I need find general solution and also A and B. But with using this theorem.

Comment: It is commonly called Abel's identity and not Abel's theorem (the theorem is about something else)

Comment: By Abel's identity you get: $W(y_1,y_2)(t) = W(y_1,y_2)(t_0)\exp(t_0 - t)$. Therefore
$$W(y_1,y_2)(t) = W(y_1,y_2)(t_0)e^{t_0 - t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $y=Ce^{at}$

Thus our equation becomes:

$$a^2y+ay-2y=0$$

(Notice the derivative of y has y in it so hence I have decided to just keep the y's equation)

We divide out the common terms to find

$$a^2+a-2=0$$

Factor this into

$$(a+2)(a-1) =0$$

This the general solution is a linear combination of this:

$$y = C_1e^{-2t}+C_2e^{at}$$

I'm not sure if your question states $t(y=0)=0$ or if it means $y(t=0) = 0$

But based on that initial condition you can set values to the constants in our general solution. I will leave you to do that :)